# lebesgue measurability sufficient and necessary conditions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I was reading a proof ("my question is also about the steps in the proof itself which I will type out here also") regarding a necessary and sufficient condition for measurability. In particular the theorem says:

A subset A $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an open set $G \supset A$ such that $\mu ^{*}(G \setminus A) < \epsilon$.

Proof:

First we assume that A is measurable and show that it satisfies the condition given in the theorem. 
Suppose that $\mu(A) < \infty$ and let $\epsilon >0$. From (2.12) there is an open set $G \supset A$ such that $\mu(G) < \mu^{*}(A) + \epsilon$. Then since A is measurable,

$\mu^{*}(G\setminus A) = \mu^{*}(G)- \mu^{*}(G\cap A) = \mu(G)-\mu^{*}(A) < \epsilon$

---

My question is specifically regarding the second last step of the expression which is this:

$\mu(G)-\mu^{*}(A)$

I am not sure how the $\mu^{*}(G)$ becomes $\mu(G)$ because I was reading that if G is a rectangle in $R^n$, then yes we have $\mu^{*}(G)$ would equal $\mu(G)$. But in this case, the conditions for the proof only states that G is an open set that contains A (it did not say G is a rectangle, all it says is G is an open set in the statement of the theorem). So I am not sure how the author can use $\mu^{*}(G)$ = $\mu(G)$ in the proof.

Could someone kindly give me some hints as to what the author has used or which part am I missing? The symbol $\mu^{*} (G)$ means the outer-measure of the set $G$. The symbol without the star (i.e. $\mu(G)$) means measure (i.e. it means the usual sense of volume for a box, or the usual sense of area for a 2D-rectangle, or the length for a 1D line). For example, $\mu(G)$ = 27, if G is a rectangle of sides 3 and 9, and in this case $\mu^{*}(G)= \mu(G)$ because we have G being a rectangle. But the theorem only says G is an open set, so I am not sure how the author proves the theorem in particular the steps in the second last statement.

Thank you for your help

Comment: From what book/paper is the proof? It hasn't been shown before that $\mu^*(G) = \mu(G)$ for all open $G$?

Comment: It is Theorem 2.24 here:  https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m206/measure_notes.pdf

Comment: also sorry do you mean the outer measure of an open set G equal to the measure of the set G?  so for any open set K, the outer measure of K would equal the measure of K?  i.e. $\mu^{*}(K) = \mu(K)$

Comment: It follows from Theorem 2.23, formula (2.9), that $\mu^*(G) = \mu(G)$ if $G$ is open.

Comment: sorry md2perpe, but could you elaborate more how 2.23 formula 2.9 would mean that $\mu^{*}(G)=\mu(G)$?

Comment: If I substitute $G$ into 2.9, then yes $G$ is surely a subset of itself, i.e. $G \subset G$. But how do I know that $G$ is actually the set that will contain $G$ AND at the same time the measure of this set $G$ is the minimum?  what if there are other sets such as $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...A_n...$ and the union say of all those sets are open and the measure of the union of those set are smaller than $G$? i.e. $ \mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{N} A_{i}) < \mu(G)$?

Comment: $$\mu^*(G) = \inf \{ \mu(G') : G \subset G', G' \text{ open}\}$$
Since $G$ is open, $\mu(G)$ is among the values over which we take infimum, so $\mu^*(G) \leq \mu(G)$. But since we take infimum over supersets, and $\mu$ is increasing, we also have $\mu^*(G) \geq \mu(G)$. Thus, $\mu^*(G) = \mu(G)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63140/discussion-between-john-w-and-md2perpe).

Comment: Hi md2perpe, sorry actually one more question, could you explain what you mean when you said "But since we .... we also have $\mu^{*}(G) = \mu(G)$ " just in the very last comment here above ?

Comment: Since $G \subset G'$ and therefore $\mu(G) \leq \mu(G')$ we have $\mu(G) \leq \inf \{ \mu(G') \} = \mu^*(G)$. Now we have shown both $\mu^*(G) \leq \mu(G)$ and $\mu^(G) \geq \mu(G)$ so we can conclude $\mu^*(G) = \mu(G)$.

Comment: Hi, I understand the first inequality i.e. $\mu^{*}(G) \le \mu(G)$, but could you explain the second inequality, how do you get $\mu^{*}(G) \ge \mu(G)$.

Comment: Hi md2perpe, could you explain the second inequality if you are free? thank you

Comment: Which inequality do you refer to?

Comment: the second one that you have which is $\mu^{*}(G) \geq \mu(G)$. You said "so we can conclude $\mu^{*}(G) \geq \mu(G)$".  Thank you.

Comment: For every measurable (e.g. open) $G' \supseteq G$ we have $\mu(G') \geq \mu(G)$. Therefore $\mu^*(G) = \inf \{ \mu(G') : G \subset G', G' \text{ open}\} \geq \mu(G).$

This relies on the general obvious result that if all elements in a set are at least as big as a specific value, then also the infimum of the elements is at least as big as that specific value:
$$\inf \{ x \in A \mid x \geq a \} \geq a.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\mu(G) = \mu^*(G)$ by definition of $\mu$.  See Definition 2.10 in your notes. This only makes sense where $\mu$ is defined, which is on measurable sets.  All Borel sets, including open sets, are measurable (theorem 2.21).

Possible confusion arises, I speculate, because "$\mu$" is used for the volume of "rectangles" before defining $\mu$ as Lebesgue measure.  So the context of following Definition 2.10 is important.  The stuff about proving that $\mu^*(R)=\mu(R)$ for rectangles ensures consistency of the notation later, but it is overloaded/abused and takes getting used to.  Get used to knowing that $\mu = \mu^*$ wherever the former is defined.